# Recursive Definition notation example

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my textbook, the author shows this example of recursion, and I can't make heads or tails of it. Can someone give a better explanation of this...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The definition has two parts. The first one should look at least somewhat tautological - it simply states that the sum of *one* thing is itself. Nothing too complex there.

The more interesting piece of the definition is the second part. Rather than look at this somewhat complex piece of notation, let's just think of how we'd define:

$$\sum_{k=m}^{m+1}a_k$$

This is nothing more than a sum of two things - that is, $a_m + a_{m+1}$. Remember, however, that $a_m = \sum_{k=m}^{m}a_k$. So we can write this second sum as

$$\sum_{k=m}^{m+1}a_k = \sum_{k=m}^m a_k +a_{m+1}$$

By the exact same argument, you can figure out that:

$$\sum_{k=m}^{m+2}a_k = \sum_{k=m}^{m+1} a_k +a_{m+2}$$

...and so on, and so on. The "recursive definition" is just extending this to any integer $n>m$.

Comment: In your last example, why is the final term am+2 and not am+1

Comment: When the upper limit is m+1, does that mean that the lower limit gets +1 after each iteration

Answer (score 0):

The less mathematical definition is to note that:

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^m a_k = \underbrace{a_m + \cdots + a_k + \cdots + a_m}_{\text{$m-m+1$ terms}} = a_m$

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^n a_k = \underbrace{a_m + \cdots + a_k + \cdots + a_n}_{\text{$n-m+1$ terms}} = \underbrace{a_m + \cdots + a_k + \cdots + a_{n-1}}_{\text{$n-m$ terms}}+ a_n = \color{gray}{\left(\color{black}{\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n-1} a_k}\right)} + a_n$

---

The mathematical definition is basically, that when given something of the form, $S_{m,m} = a_m \cap S_{m,n} = S_{m,n+1}+a_n$ and a sequence $\{a_k\mid k\in\{m,\ldots,n\}\}$ then we can evaluate $S_{m,n}$ through recursion.